# Created MySQL database. Can modify/query the DB using PHPmyAdmin, but can't connect via PHP/SQL script?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I'm trying to build a website based on a mySQL database. I've installed XAMPP and, using the included PHPmyAdmin, have developed that simple database.

Via PHPmyAdmin I can edit/query the database without problems. But, when I try to embed these queries in PHP script, I can't seem to select the database.

Google returned a few suggestions of common causes of this, but none of them seemed to be my error. There are no port-clashing problems and SQL is running fine. The localhost itself works fine. I can use it to test normal PHP scripts without problems. The problems only arise when I try to connect to an SQL database.

Below is my PHP script with SQL query included.

header and footer are just place-holders. As of right now they just contain HTML opening and closing tags.

When I run open this in a browser I get: " Failed to select database " and nothing else.

Can you see where I'm going wrong? or perhaps hint at what the problem might be?

Thanks for your time!

```
<?php include("header.php");?>

<?php
$connect= mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");

$db = mysql_select_db("educross_content_db, $connect") or die ("Failed to select database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'content_table'.* FROM 'content_table' ");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ){

    $FileName = $row['FILENAME'];
    $FileDescription = $row['FILEDESCRIPTION'];
    $FilePath = $row['FILE_PATH'];

    echo "FileName: " . $FILENAME . "<br/>";
    echo "FileDescription" . $FILEDESCRIPTION . "<br/>";
    echo "FilePath : " . $FilePath . "<br/>";
  }

mysql_close($connect);
?>;

<?php include("footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add an extra quotation mark after the db to properly terminate it:

```
$db = mysql_select_db("educross_content_db", $connect) or die ("Failed to select database");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced quotation mark in the argument to mysql_select_db. Change it to this:

```
$db = mysql_select_db("educross_content_db", $connect) or die ("Failed to select database");
```